# Why is there distortion when the cube is on the edge of the screen?

Tags: python-3.x, math, pygame, 3d, rendering

I have made a cube renderer from scratch using pygame.I have been following a guide online and translating it into python and have been pretty successful until I started playing around with the program. Everything works fine, however I noticed that when the cube is further from the center, there is a big distortion effect. Like, unreasonably big distortion. Is there something wrong with how the rays are calculated?
(Arrow keys to move camera)

```
import pygame

width = 720
height = 480
red = (255, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0,0,0)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
running = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
runSpeed = 30

cube = [0, 0, 0], [8, 0, 0], [8, 0, 8], [0, 0, 8], [0, 8, 0], [8, 8, 0], [8, 8, 8], [0, 8, 8]
cubeCoords = [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]
moveCubeCoords = [8, -4, -4]
camCoord = [0, 0, 0]
camSpeed = 1
canvasDis = 1
scale = 80


def coordConvert(x, y):
    newX = (width / 2) + x
    newY = (height / 2) + y
    return newX, newY


def drawCircle(x, y):
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, red, (x, y), 5)


def moveCube():
    for i in range(len(cube)):
        for e in range(3):
            cube[i][e] = cube[i][e] + moveCubeCoords[e]


def onEvent(event):
    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        camCoord[1] = camCoord[1] + camSpeed
    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        camCoord[1] = camCoord[1] - camSpeed
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        camCoord[2] = camCoord[2] + camSpeed
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        camCoord[2] = camCoord[2] - camSpeed
    print(camCoord)


def main():
    pygame.init()
    print("Initialized")
    pygame.display.set_caption("Cube rendering")
    moveCube()

    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                onEvent(event)

        for i, point in enumerate(cube):  # gets all coords of cube
            pX = point[0] - camCoord[0]
            pY = point[1] - camCoord[1]
            pZ = point[2] - camCoord[2]
            mpX = pZ / pX
            mpY = pY / -pX  # canvas Y deviation from origin
            newCoords = coordConvert(mpX * scale, mpY * scale)
            cubeCoords[i][0] = newCoords[0]
            cubeCoords[i][1] = newCoords[1]
            drawCircle(newCoords[0], newCoords[1])

        for i in range(4):  # Vert lines
            pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (cubeCoords[i][0], cubeCoords[i][1]),
                             (cubeCoords[i + 4][0], cubeCoords[i + 4][1]), 2)
        for i in range(3):# Bottom lines
            pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (cubeCoords[i][0], cubeCoords[i][1]),
                             (cubeCoords[i + 1][0], cubeCoords[i + 1][1]), 2)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (cubeCoords[3][0], cubeCoords[3][1]),
                         (cubeCoords[0][0], cubeCoords[0][1]), 2)
        for i in range(3): # Top lines
            pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (cubeCoords[i+4][0], cubeCoords[i+4][1]),
                             (cubeCoords[i + 5][0], cubeCoords[i + 5][1]), 2)
        #lazy lines
        pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (cubeCoords[3][0], cubeCoords[3][1]),
                         (cubeCoords[0][0], cubeCoords[0][1]), 2)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (cubeCoords[7][0], cubeCoords[7][1]),
                         (cubeCoords[4][0], cubeCoords[4][1]), 2)
        print(cubeCoords)
        clock.tick(runSpeed)
        pygame.display.update()
        screen.fill(white)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Check [this](https://handwiki.org/wiki/Perspective_projection_distortion) out. Fig. 2 is probably what you see..

Comment: @mikuszefski Even though the cube side isn't perpendicular to the camera like the figure shown, would this effect still take place?

Comment: I would be surprised if this effect would require "perpendicular"

Answer (score 0):

The only location that a cubemap IS properly projected is the center of the cube.  The images have distortion baked into them and seeing them from any other angle with begin to distort.
If you want to move your player around an area you can make the cube REALLY large to minimize the distortion as the player won't move far from the center relative to the cube.  This is typical in game environments.

Here's an explanation of cube map projection.
http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/Cube_map

Answer (score 0):

What can see is called [Perspective distortion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_distortion_(photography)).

Anyway you can simplify and cleanup the code:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 400))
width, height = window.get_size()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

cube = [-1, -1, -1], [1, -1, -1], [1, -1, 1], [-1, -1, 1], [-1, 1, -1], [1, 1, -1], [1, 1, 1], [-1, 1, 1]
edges = [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 0), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 4), (0, 4), (1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7)]
cam_coord, cam_speed = [0, 0, 0], 0.5
scale = 200

translate = [4, 0, 0]
for i in range(len(cube)):
    for e in range(3):
        cube[i][e] += translate[e]

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    cam_coord[1] -= (keys[pygame.K_DOWN] - keys[pygame.K_UP]) * cam_speed
    cam_coord[2] -= (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT]) * cam_speed

    cube_coords = []
    for point in cube:
        x = (width / 2) + scale * (point[2] - cam_coord[2]) / (point[0] - cam_coord[0])
        y = (height / 2) +  scale * (point[1] - cam_coord[1]) / (point[0] - cam_coord[0])
        cube_coords.append((x, y))

    window.fill((255, 255, 255))
    for edge in edges:
        pygame.draw.line(window, (0, 0, 0), cube_coords[edge[0]], cube_coords[edge[1]], 2)
    for coord in cube_coords:
        pygame.draw.circle(window, (255, 0, 0), coord, 5)
    pygame.display.update()
    
pygame.quit()
exit()
```